# Filtrar columnas de fecha según condición pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Dispongo de un dataframe cuyos nombres de columnas son fecha en formato '%m/%d/%y' y quiero filtrar el df según si la columna cumple una condición, en este caso que sea menor que otra fecha.

Para tratar fecha, he pasado ambas a datetime y luego usando strftime de nuevo al formato, pero no consigo que me filtre.

```
Pais           1/22/20    2/20/20    7/2/20
Afghanistan     100         20         5
Albania         50          10         3
Algeria         30          0          0
```

Os pongo ejemplo del csv y del código.

```
fecha = pd.to_datetime("01-06-20",format = '%d-%m-%y')
columnas_fecha = pd.to_datetime(df2.columns,format = '%m/%d/%y')
df_f = pd.DataFrame(data=columnas_fecha)
fechas_validas = list(df_f[df_f[0]<fecha][0])

fechas_finales = [i.strftime('%m/%d/%y') for i in fechas_validas]
```

cuando intento filtrar el df:

```
df2.loc[:,fechas_finales]
```

el resultado debería eliminar la última columna ya que es > '01-06-20'

el error es este:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['01/22/20', '01/23/20', '01/24/20', '01/25/20', '01/26/20', '01/27/20',\n       '01/28/20', '01/29/20', '01/30/20', '01/31/20',\n       ...\n       '05/22/20', '05/23/20', '05/24/20', '05/25/20', '05/26/20', '05/27/20',\n       '05/28/20', '05/29/20', '05/30/20', '05/31/20'],\n      dtype='object', length=131)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está el csv para poder hacer pruebas?

Comment: Perdón, ya lo he añadido. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que `strftime("%m/%d/%y")` genera tanto el dígito del día como el del mes con dos cifras (rellenando con 0 por la izquierda si es necesario), por lo que al final la lista de nombres de columna a preservar te sale:

```
>>> fechas_finales
['01/22/20', '02/20/20']
```

Y esos nombres de columnas efectivamente no corresponden con los que usa el dataframe que son '1/22/20' y '2/20/20' (sin el 0 delante del mes o del día).

Esto se arregla si usas esta otra cadena de formato: `strftime("%-m/%-d/%y")`. El `-` después del `%` suprime el cero inicial. Con eso tu ejemplo ya funcionaría.

De todas formas creo que puedes simplificar un poco el código, usando `.drop()` para quitar las columnas que no quieres (en vez de `.loc[]` para seleccionar las que sí):

```
columnas_fecha = pd.to_datetime(df2.columns, format = '%m/%d/%y')
fecha = pd.to_datetime("01-06-20", format = '%d-%m-%y')
df2.drop(columns=[d.strftime('%-m/%-d/%y') for d in columnas_fecha if d>=fecha])
```

produce:

```
             1/22/20  2/20/20
Pais                         
Afghanistan      100       20
Albania           50       10
Algeria           30        0
```