# Filtrar elementos de un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, filtro

Estoy trabajando con un dataset como el siguiente:

```
    Lat      Long     1/22/20     1/23/20     1/24/20     1/25/20     1/26/20     1/27/20 ...
Country/Region                                                          
Afghanistan     33.939110   67.709953   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Albania     41.153300   20.168300   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Algeria     28.033900   1.659600    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Andorra     42.506300   1.521800    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Angola  -11.202700  17.873900   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Antigua and Barbuda     17.060800   -61.796400  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Argentina   -38.416100  -63.616700  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Armenia     40.069100   45.038200   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Australia   -256.850200     1130.843900     0   0   0   0   4   5   5   6   9   9   12  12  12
Austria     47.516200   14.550100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Azerbaijan  40.143100   47.576900   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Bahamas     25.025885   -78.035889  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Quiero hacer una función que tiene como parámetros de entrada:

- `path:` Ruta del fichero que contiene los datos
- `fecha:` fecha (string)

La función devuelve un diccionario guardado en pickle con el nombre de casos diarios por pais y por datos anteriores a el 1 de junio de 2020 (no incluido). El hecho es que en función de cual sea la fecha que reciba cómo parámetro de entrada el dataset debería quedar filtrado hasta la fecha indicada y no sé cómo hacerlo. Por el momento he conseguido hacer el código que me permite sacar el diccionario pero sin incluir el parámetro fecha. A continuación, el código:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd

path_co='data/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'

def create_covid_pickle(path_co,fecha):
    df = pd.read_csv(path_co)
    # El fichero contiene repetidos varios Country/Region, he hecho un groupby para agrupar los casos.
    df = df.groupby(['Country/Region']).sum()
    # Solo estamos interesados en obtener datos antes del 1/06/2020, las fechas posteriores se han borrado.
    df = df.drop(df.columns[133:], axis=1)
    # También se ha borrado Lat y Long ya que no sirven.
    aux = df.drop(columns=["Lat", "Long"]).to_dict(orient="split")
    # Creamos el diccionario
    d= {}
    for i, pais in enumerate(aux["index"]):
        d[pais]={"time":aux["columns"], "cases": aux["data"][i]}
    # Lo guardamos en pickle
    with open("primera_ola.pkl","wb") as tf:
        diccionari = pickle.dump(d,tf)
    return diccionari
```

A continuación, el código para testear:

```
 #Cómo se puede ver la función tiene cómo parámetros (path, fecha) sin embargo no soy capaz de filtrar los 
    datos por fecha.
    create_covid_pickle("data/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv","01-06-20")
    # Load and print some data
    country_cases = pickle.load(open("primera_ola.pkl", "rb"))
    print("The number of countries is {}".format(len(country_cases)))
    print("The timeseries of Andorra is {}".format(country_cases["Andorra"]))
```

La salida deberia ser algo como lo siguiente y variable en función de la fecha indicada ya que variará los datos contenidos en el diccionario:

```
The number of countries is 192
The timeseries of Andorra is {'time': ['1/22/20', '1/23/20', '1/24/20', '1/25/20', '1/26/20', '1/27/20', '1/28/20', '1/29/20', '1/30/20', '1/31/20', '2/1/20', '2/2/20', '2/3/20', '2/4/20', '2/5/20', '2/6/20', '2/7/20', '2/8/20', '2/9/20', '2/10/20', '2/11/20', '2/12/20', '2/13/20', '2/14/20', '2/15/20', '2/16/20', '2/17/20', '2/18/20', '2/19/20', '2/20/20', '2/21/20', '2/22/20', '2/23/20', '2/24/20', '2/25/20', '2/26/20', '2/27/20', '2/28/20', '2/29/20', '3/1/20', '3/2/20', '3/3/20', '3/4/20', '3/5/20', '3/6/20', '3/7/20', '3/8/20', '3/9/20', '3/10/20', '3/11/20', '3/12/20', '3/13/20', '3/14/20', '3/15/20', '3/16/20', '3/17/20', '3/18/20', '3/19/20', '3/20/20', '3/21/20', '3/22/20', '3/23/20', '3/24/20', '3/25/20', '3/26/20', '3/27/20', '3/28/20', '3/29/20', '3/30/20', '3/31/20', '4/1/20', '4/2/20', '4/3/20', '4/4/20', '4/5/20', '4/6/20', '4/7/20', '4/8/20', '4/9/20', '4/10/20', '4/11/20', '4/12/20', '4/13/20', '4/14/20', '4/15/20', '4/16/20', '4/17/20', '4/18/20', '4/19/20', '4/20/20', '4/21/20', '4/22/20', '4/23/20', '4/24/20', '4/25/20', '4/26/20', '4/27/20', '4/28/20', '4/29/20', '4/30/20', '5/1/20', '5/2/20', '5/3/20', '5/4/20', '5/5/20', '5/6/20', '5/7/20', '5/8/20', '5/9/20', '5/10/20', '5/11/20', '5/12/20', '5/13/20', '5/14/20', '5/15/20', '5/16/20', '5/17/20', '5/18/20', '5/19/20', '5/20/20', '5/21/20', '5/22/20', '5/23/20', '5/24/20', '5/25/20', '5/26/20', '5/27/20', '5/28/20', '5/29/20', '5/30/20', '5/31/20'], 'cases': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 39, 39, 53, 75, 88, 113, 133, 164, 188, 224, 267, 308, 334, 370, 376, 390, 428, 439, 466, 501, 525, 545, 564, 583, 601, 601, 638, 646, 659, 673, 673, 696, 704, 713, 717, 717, 723, 723, 731, 738, 738, 743, 743, 743, 745, 745, 747, 748, 750, 751, 751, 752, 752, 754, 755, 755, 758, 760, 761, 761, 761, 761, 761, 761, 762, 762, 762, 762, 762, 763, 763, 763, 763, 764, 764, 764]}
```

Comment: Parece que hay alguien más trabajando en un problema muy similar. De hecho yo pensaba que eras tú.... Mira [esta respuesta mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/444460/7123) a ese otro usuario, que quería filtrar por fecha las columnas de un dataframe igual al tuyo, e intenta combinar esa solución con lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Si! Soy yo! Pero ahora que tengo el dataframe mi pregunta es como puedo crear la funcion pra que el diccionario coja los datos en funcion de la fecha dada

Comment: Pues puedes aplicar el mismo truco que en la otra respuesta al dataframe `df` que recibes como parámetro, es decir, hacerle un `drop()` de todas las columnas que tengan fecha superior a la que recibe como parámetro, y ya después obtienes el diccionario a partir de ese `df` filtrado. ¿no?

Comment: Esto es lo que hecho si te fijas. El problema es que tiene que ser una funcion y la ultima columna tiene que variar en funcion de la fecha input

Comment: Pues no, la verdad, me he fijado y sigo sin verlo. La función `create_covid_pickle()` dices que recibe dos parámetros, siendo el segundo la fecha, pero no es así. La que has escrito en la pregunta recibe un solo parámetro. Por otro lado veo que te quedas con las 133 primeras columnas, pero en ningún sitio veo que compares con ninguna fecha para hacer un `drop()` de las columnas por encima de una fecha.

Comment: He modificado la función con el segundo parámetro "fecha". No lo había incluido porqué no sabia como hacerlo aunque estaba explicado en el texto. Perdón por el malentendido. Si, me quedo con las primeras 133, es decir, 133 fechas. De estas 133, los datos recogidos en el diccionario seran todos aquellos hasta la fecha indicada por el usuario.

Comment: A ver, lo que yo te digo es que añadas dentro de la función, antes de la línea que hace el `.to_dict()`, un filtro del estilo `df = df.drop(columns=[d.strftime('%-m/%-d/%y') for d in columnas_fecha if d>=fecha])` como se hizo en la otra respuesta (tendrás que meter también el código que genera asigna `fecha` y `columnas_fecha`, como en la otra pregunta. De ese modo el `df` resultante ya tiene solo las fechas que te interesan, y cuando lo conviertas a dict ya saldrá lo que quieres.